# Crystal report throw error when reused

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I do a programmatically bind to my crystal report viewr like

```
DataTable orderDtSrc = GetDataFromdb(txtOrderNo.Text);     
rptViewer.ReportSource = new ReportDocument();
                if (orderDtSrc != null)
                {
                    ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
                    report.Load(Server.MapPath("Design/MyReport.rpt"));
                    report.SetDataSource(orderDtSrc);
                    report.SummaryInfo.ReportTitle = "Report No-" + orderDtSrc.Rows[0]["OrderNumber"].ToString();
                    rptViewer.ReportSource = report;
                    rptViewer.DataBind();
                }
```

So It will get the data throw the `GetDataFromdb(txtOrderNo.Text);` which get data by order number provided by user.

first call it will get the report and bind the viewer with no problem then if I put a new order number in the textbox and then click on show report button which call the previous function I got this exception.

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: inputString
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
 if (orderDtSrc != null  && orderDtSrc.Rows.Count >0)
```